# DRF how can get count of rows from multiple models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models, how can I get the count of rows each of them(using DRF) by one request?

```
class Question(AbstractArticle):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)

class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the count and pass it simply like this:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from models import Question,Service
from rest_framework import status
class GetCount(APIView):
    #use your proper authentication/permission classes here
    def get(self,request):
        question_count=Question.objects.count()
        service_count= Service.objects.count() 

        return Response({"question":question_count,"service":service_count},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a view and override get method.

```
 from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView
 from rest_framework.response import Response

 class TotalCountAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            count_qsn = Question.objects.count()
            count_srvc = Service.objects.count()
            return Response(data= {'count_qsn':count_qsn, 'count_srvc': count_srvc})
```